# Android WebDriver does not load https pages using the Android Test Framework

Tags: android, selenium, https, selenium-webdriver, android-testing

How do you load https pages on Android WebDriver with the Android Test Framework on an AVD?
According to the AndroidDriver FAQ (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Android_fails_to_load_HTTPS_pages) you need to enable capabilities when making the new AndroidDriver:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android();
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(caps);
```

However when using the Android Test Framework the driver used is AndroidWebDriver and not AndroidDriver. In the AndroidDriver constructor you can use capability as a parameter to allow https pages but in the AndroidWebDriver constructor the only parameter is the Activity  that needs to be used. So how would you set the capabilities in order to allow AndroidWebDriver to load https pages?

Answer (score 0):

try to export certificate from your website and import this certificate to your android device (google: hoe to import certificate android).
after this steps I got ability to visit HTTPS in my tests.